# MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to import a SQL file into the database but facing this error. Please help if anyone can solve this error.

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` json NOT NULL,
  `expiration_date` date ,
  `barcode` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `name` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bundle_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `shelf_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_request_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `weight` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `products_bundle_id_foreign` (`bundle_id`),
  KEY `products_shelf_id_foreign` (`shelf_id`),
  KEY `products_delivery_request_id_foreign` (`delivery_request_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json NOT NULL,
  `expiration_date` date ,
  `barcode` varchar(125) COLLATE utf8m' at line 5
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: You must be using MySql version < 5.7

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Your statement [works fine in MySql 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a873bf0a7e68fbe7c6deb35b549ec2dd)